# Installing Ubunu 16.04 Windows 8 Dual Boot (VERY CLOSE)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 16.04, windows-8, default

So i have successfully installed ubuntu 16 on a windows 8 with uefi. My only problem is in order to get to the grub boot screen i have to press esc during boot.  I want grub to load in by default, not the os boot manager.

Edit1: Here is the link i found but it is a bit too complicated for me (First time linux user) http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-System-and-Recovery/Changing-Boot-Order-on-Dual-Boot-Windows-8-and-Ubuntu/m-p/3384985/highlight/true#M172240

Comment: I will be looking into this soon on one of my pc's. I see there are a few pages on the net about getting the two to work together with uefi. Can you share the one that worked for you please.

Comment: @philUK Absolutely. I honestly just followed the ubuntu tutorial they have on the downloads page.  It was super easy to install, only thing i had to do was shrink the windows partition to make room for ubuntu. Im a first time ubuntu user so the cli is scary but im working through it. I could install with or without legacy mode and same for secure boot. The only problem im running into is making grub boot by default.  Right now in order to see grub with ubuntu and windows 8 i have to press esc  and choose ubuntu and then it boots grub. Everything worked great other than this.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu, use the command

```
sudo efibootmgr -v
```

to see the UEFI boot order,
and the command

```
sudo efibootmgr -o XXXX,YYYY,...
```

where the XXXX etc. are the numnbers on the boot items.
Put Ubuntu's shimx64.efi bootloader first, or grubx64.efi if you are not using secure boot.

---

On some machines you might need to set the UEFI Settings/BIOS supervisor password before making any permanent changes in nvram entries.

---

google "efibootmgr can't change boot order"  and there are many solutions posted (some here) for this problem.

Comment: So now i just deleted the boot order with a -O command and then typed them all in, i know it worked because it showed me the boot order i wanted it to do which is grub first. However i restarted and it took me to windows lol. sigh

Comment: Well ive added an admin password to bios.  Ubuntu nor grub shows up under the device list for legacy or regular. Within linux command line i can make changes to boot order and it shows the change but nothing is actually changed when i boot.

Comment: Looks like i found a "hack" to get it working that sort of looks like renaming the files for the os boot manager so it won't be able to find it.  Im a new linux user and the command line instructions are too complicated in link. 

Here is where everyone can go to view the fix. HP Hard coded uefi to reset boot options for windows every time its booted...so no matter the change it will always change back to regular os boot. [here is link](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-System-and-Recovery/Changing-Boot-Order-on-Dual-Boot-Windows-8-and-Ubuntu/m-p/3384985/highlight/true#M172240)